# Google Tag Manager Data Layer

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up GTM and GA and have been able to track several events successfully, so the basics of each seem to be set up correctly.  I am now experimenting with the DataLayer and am having a little trouble.

I have a link that opens a donate page and am trying to capture the element id and page title of the page on which this is fired.  I am seeing the event captured in GA but the label is null.

1) I am not sure where to see the values from the datalayer if they are being passed?

I have it set up like this

```
    <head>
         <!-- Google Analytics here -->
         <script>
            dataLayer = [{}];
         </script>
         <!-- other stuff -->
         <!-- Google Tag Manager here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

And then

```
<a href="donate" class="randomizer" dataLayer.push({'donateId':'donate0','donatePage':'Page Name)' });>Donation</a>.
```

So 2) am I set up correctly?

On the GA side I have the dimensions donateId and donatePage set up under custom definitions>custom dimensions

```
donateId   Index=1, Scope=Hit, State-Active
donatePage Index=2, Scope=Hit, State=Active
```

I also see the code

```
var dimensionValue = 'SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
```

3) but I'm not sure where to put this?

4) is this not working because the event causes a new page to open?

So 4 questions in 1 but any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you need to use **onclick** attribute.

Try to modify the link like following:

```
<a href="donate" class="randomizer" onclick="dataLayer.push({'donateId':'donate0','donatePage':'Page Name)' });">Donation</a>
```